# How can I have refresh page link/button inside my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, web

Basically I have the following code which checks the user input and gives the output accordingly:

```
<script>
    function checkUserInput() 
    {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
        var stringToCheckAgainst = random_images_array[num].split('.');
        if (userInput.toUpperCase() == stringToCheckAgainst[0].toUpperCase())         
        {
            document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML="<p>" + txt.fontsize(5) + "</p>";document.close();
        } 
        else 
        {

            //user has inputted an incorrect string
            document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML="<p>" + txt1.fontsize(5) + "</p>";document.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

However my problem is, in the case that the user response is not correct and the programme only displays the “incorrect message”, I need to show a refresh or reset button or text that by clicking on that link the user can again refresh the page and gets a new challenge.

Comment: Can you show what is happening by doing this in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can't you add something like this? <a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">Reload</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkUserInput() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    var stringToCheckAgainst = random_images_array[num].split('.');

    if (userInput.toUpperCase() == stringToCheckAgainst[0].toUpperCase()) {
        document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML="<p>" + txt.fontsize(5) + "</p>";document.close();
    } else {
        //user has inputted an incorrect string
        document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML="<p>" + txt1.fontsize(5) + "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:location.reload();'>Try again</a></p>";document.close();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I make the “please try again” font bigger size?

Comment: with css. Create a class and apply it to your item.